# How to check correct subdomain in cucumber & rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber

Currently I have scenario where i need to test following circumstances.

- If i fill up text-field with school name.
- Then it should go to that subdomain url

Eg. If I put xyz college in text field then it should got to xz.lvh.me:3000
shortname for xyz college is xz which is stored in database.

homepage.feature
      Feature: Home Page
        Need to check university field

```
  Scenario Outline: Fill up universities
    When i fillup university name "<name>"
    Then it should go to their login page "<subdomain>"

  Examples:
    | name |   subdomain |
    | sp College  |  sp  |
```

homepage.rb

```
When /^i fillup university name "([^"]*)"$/ do |name|
  visit @@url
  choose('institution_category_school')
  fill_in "search_institution_name", :with => name
  click_button "Go"
end

Then /^it should go to their login page "([^"]*)"$/ do |subdomain|
  #so i need to check that produced url == "#{subdomain}.lvh.me:3000/"
end
```

and below is my configuration file.
support/env.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'
require 'rspec'

Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
Capybara.default_selector = :css

module Helpers
  def without_resynchronize
    page.driver.options[:resynchronize] = false
    yield
    page.driver.options[:resynchronize] = true
  end
end

World(Capybara::DSL, Helpers)

@@url= "http://lvh.me:3000/"
```

Using Rails 3.1.1, cucumber 1.1.4, rspec 2.8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Capybara, you can get the browser's current url using:

`current_url`

Then you can use your normal rspec assertions:

```
current_url.should == "#{subdomain}.lvh.me:3000/"
```

Comment: I am visiting a page in my spec using capybara `visit` and then clicking another button which is redirecting it to another page. On the third line when I print the current_url, it still shows the old (first url) rather than the second one. I am using `selenium-webdriver` for chrome. Any idea on why it is happening?

Comment: @Ava, off the top of my head there is no obvious reason. If you open an new question, you are more likely to get better support than adding a comment here.